# Magento 2.2 how to change header link create an account text to icon

Tags: magento2.2, header, toplinks

[image]

I want to change create an account text to icon.

I can find the layout file under

> *var\www\html\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\layout\default.xml*

```
 <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
</block>
```

How to change create an account text to icon

Comment: Its working. Thx Patel

Comment: Yr Welcome.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML of register link is generated from block `RegisterLink.php` so you need to **override block and add new css class in `function _toHtml()`**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Account/RegisterLink.php

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->_registration->isAllowed()
        || $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)
    ) {
        return '';
    }

    return '<li class="register-link"><a ' . $this->getLinkAttributes() . ' ></a></li>';
}
```

Now add new class in css file

```
li.register-link:before {
    font-size: 22px;
    content: '\e611';
    font-family: 'luma-icons';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way, define template to your block **template="your/template/pathhere.html"** and replace **your/template/pathhere.html** with template file path:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" template="your/template/pathhere.html" name="register-link" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

And inside your template you can use icon/image to display icon/image and can call `getHref` to get link url that you can use to link that icon.
Also you can call `$block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel())` to **get label** in your template.